# dynamically generated parent key into another query

Tags: sql, jdbctemplate

I have to take a value from one table which I have just added using seq.nextval(say Query 1) into another table for entering further information into another table through Query 2.I have used objects to pass values to the sql(oracle).I am using Spring framework's JDBCTemplate.

Can you help me with that.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Comment: thanks guys.i guess eq.currval is doing the job...couldnt post code because of company policy !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use seq.currval to get the current value of the sequence, and include that in your subsequent insert.